# regarding calling a javascript function in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In this "onclick" is working but it is not calling javascript function.please help how to execute both onclick and onclientclick at the same time.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFare"  OnClientClick="return initialize();"  runat="server"  Text="Calculate Fare" onclick="btnFare_Click"/>
```

please suggest way to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does happen on the button click? What does the javascript console say? Any errors? Exceptions?

Comment: Please post your code.  What you pasted looks correct, so its hard to tell why its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say what's wrong until you've posted more of your code.  When I run in to this problem, there are a few things I check for:

1) Is the javascript I'm calling actually in the page?  (This can be problematic for beginners because there are a few ways to include javascript in their pages, and sometimes they *think* their javascript is in the page when it actually isn't.)

2) When I call the javascript, what error do I get in the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)?  Can I see output from console.log('some text') when I include it in my function?

3) Is my javascript actually firing, but I'm missing it because I have a server-side event firing right after it?

4) Does onClientClick function return a boolean value? In this case, this is important because if it returns true, the server-side onClick event will fire.  If it returns false, the server-side event will not fire.

These are just a few things to check for.  You may want to check into [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) -- its pretty awesome when it comes to debugging things like this.

Comment: but sir there is no error in my function it is working on html button click but not on asp.net button click because server side event is getting fired

Comment: @Ashutosh: I'm not really sure what you're getting at. Put an alert() in your javascript function and then click the button. If its working, you'll get a popup box before the page posts back.  If you don't get a popup box, its not working and something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `btnFare_Click` to be fired then `initialize();` has to `return true`.

I would suggest you adding the `initialize()` like this in `page_Load`:

```
btnFare.Attributes.Add("onclick","return initialize();");
```

Instead of having it like this:

```
OnClientClick="return initialize();"
```

Comment: The OP is saying the function is not being called. This answer isn't addressing that.

Comment: The OP is saying the function is not being called. This answer isn't addressing that. – Oded 1 hour ago
but sir there is no error in my function it is working on html button click but not on asp.net button click because server side event is getting fired

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `initialize();` returns `true`. The event handler can return a boolean (`true` or `false`), and `false` means: “don’t take the default action”.

Check in javascript console if you have any js errors.

Comment: The OP is saying the function is not being called. This answer isn't addressing that.

Comment: but sir there is no error in my function it is working on html button click but not on asp.net button click because server side event is getting fired

Answer (score 0):

Problem is definitely in your initialize() function. It is returninh false i think.

Let us see the source if you have no problem.

alternatively you can put `alert(yourreturnvariable);`

as the last line in your function to check if it is really returning true.